# Magento automatically round up product price based on applied VAT

Tags: price, rounding

I need to rounds up the including vat sell price to closest £0.99 ie. if sell price for an item including vat is `£10.52` it rounds up the sell price inc vat to `£10.99` . In other words, so sell price always ends with `£.99` at the end.

And the website automatically will need to change the excluding vat price to exactly 20% less that the rounded up price.

I believe there is some event where I can hook a function to apply this round up logic?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the "5 Rappen Rounding" in Switzerland, where the total always is a multiple of 0.05.

There is an extension for it that you should be able to build upon: https://github.com/openstream/Magento5CentRounding - it rewrites the subtotal and grandtotal models and hooks into their collect() methods.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer to the question, but as a comment it would be unreadable :-/*

Why do you want to do this?

Just configure magento to use price including tax, then set the prices where you want them. Magento handles the tax stuff for you.

If you then need to upround the prices, you can implement an observer which corrects the price to `$product->setPrice(round($product->getPrice())-0.01)` in the `catalog_product_save_before` event

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful opinion. Problem is, the tax rate might vary based on region, so I can't save the rounded price.

Comment: Magento applies the taxes depending on the shipping or invoice country - you can configure this in the backend too!

Comment: Yes, but problem is, whatever the final price after applying the tax is, I need that price to the closest £0.99

Comment: As I answered: implement an observer, round the price up and magento will handle the tax stuff

Comment: `catalog_product_save_before` will set my original product price.